# bash tab auto-complete is too slow but it isn't with teraterm or putty

Tags: bash, ubuntu, autocomplete

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and it got stuck in 1~2 seconds when I push the tab button for auto-completion.

I've been trying to resolve this problem but I couldn't make it. I even changed my computer to the new one but it has same problem.

One weird thing is that when I connect my ubuntu with ssh in other pc(using teraterm or putty or other pc's ubuntu), the problem is gone and works well.

I don't know why.. Could it be a network problem? My ubuntu pc is behind the firewall and proxy but my companies' ubuntu next to me works well.

Is there anything suspicious to you?

Comment: Did you try asking this in [https://askubuntu.com/](https://askubuntu.com/) ?

Comment: @deepakchethan No I didn't. Apparently, That is better place to ask kind of this question. Thank you.

Comment: compare the command `complete`'s output to see if there's any diff between local login and remote ssh login.

Comment: @pynexj I tried the command that you said. And there's no difference at all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the answer!!

To resolve this problem, turn off the "Terminal bell" option of terminal.

In terminal,

Edit > Preferences > Sound > Terminal bell

Answer (score 0):

`sudo updatedb`

The database is rebuilt for auto completion.

Maybe check your hard disk health as this could be a hardware issue, and the disk is struggling to read, and the command is searching the database and taking longer to complete.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, I tried that command before but it didn't work. Well, I thought of the hardware problem as well, which is why I even changed the computer to new one but the new computer has a same problem:(..

Comment: What is the output, when you run the command?

Comment: There's no output returning zero.

Comment: Maybe the app bash-completion needed to be reinstalled. You can reinstall this with the following command, `sudo apt install --reinstall bash-completion`

Comment: That was already what I've done as well :( But thank you.. I'll try it agian.